# Finding the maximum of minimum values

Tags: google-sheets, max, aggregate, min, array-formulas

I would like to calculate the maximum value of the minimum values of each row in a spreadsheet (Google Sheets, specifically) that is greater than 0. I hope that makes sense. My data is:

```
0    6   7   8   1          
0   12  21  22  21          
0   10      18  24
0    7   9   1  17          
0   16  16  20
```

So, I want an ArrayFormula of some sort that will generate:

```
 1
12
10
 1
16
```

Of which I could then get the maximum. I've read and experienced that the obvious solution doesn't work, which is:

```
=max(ArrayFormula(min(if(A:Z>0,A:Z,"")))
```

The reason being the `ArrayFormula(min(...` part of it returns the minimum of the whole data set that's greater than 0, which is 1 here. If there's no nice workaround, I'll consider rearranging my data somehow, or calculating minima in separate cells, but I'm really hoping for a 1-step solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max ArrayFunction doesn't exist, so the only way is workaround. Suppose, you have some numbers in range `A1:C5`. the resulting range is `D1:D5`:

[image]

All you need is single formula in cell `D1`:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(row(A1:C5)&"*"&A1:C5&"/")),"/")),"\d+")),ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(row(A1:C5)&"*"&A1:C5&"/")),"/")),"[*](\d+)")*1)},"select Col1, min(Col2) where Col2 <>0 group by Col1 label min(Col2) ''"),"select Col2")
```

Be careful, it can work slow.

The main part of formula is query:

```
select Col1, min(Col2) where Col2 <>0 group by Col1...
```

change it to get different results (max, min, sum, avg, some calculatrions and so on)

If someone want to explore the formula, here's [worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11aKlU922CQmDng1ZSijw-31QBOEiUc9wshNQTbzzLSU/edit?usp=sharing) with step-by step solution.

Answer (score 0):

With data in the range A1:E5, in F1 and copied down:

```
=if(small(A1:E1,1)=0,small(A1:E1,2),small(A1:E1,1))
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(min(if(A2:E2>0,A2:E2,"")))
```

should return the minimum value greater than 0 per row, for which the maximum might be calculated with:

```
=max(F1:F5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to get the minimum value per row (allowing an array output in one go), try:

```
=index(ArrayFormula(transpose(query(transpose(if(A:C>0, A:C,)),"select "&join("),","min(Col"&row(indirect("A1:A"&count(A:A))))&")"))),,2)
```