# ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets with nested array functions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

The documentation of the Google Sheets function `arrayformula` says

> Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays.

This is working well in the following case which simply divides all the values in column *A* by five:

```
=arrayformula(A2:A / 5)
```

Now I want to lower-bound the result in every row by 0, i.e. in row *n* I want to compute `max(An, 0)`. This is my non-working attempt:

```
=arrayformula(max(A2:A / 5, 0))
```

The `max` itself would work perfectly without the use of `arrayformula`, i.e. if I fill `max(A2 / 5, 0)` down all rows I get exactly what I want. I want the `max` function to operate on two single values, the single value found in A*n* and the constant 0. The reason why the `arrayformula` approach is not working is that the `max` "steals" the range, aggregating the entire range `A2:A` into a single number. Thus, `arrayformula` operates on only this number and entirely ignores the range `A2:A`, consequently producing the same value for all cells.

How do I make the `arrayformula` interpret the range `A2:A`, or rather, how do I prevent the `max` function from doing so and have it operate on two single values instead?

(I can solve the issue with an `if` function instead, but that does not seem particularly elegant and requires a lot of code repetition, in particular since my real problem uses more involved arithmetic and a combination of `min` and `max`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "lower bound"? Please provide an example of a list of input values and a list of desired output.

Comment: By lower bound I mean the result should be at least 0. Hence the `max`. The division by 5 is just an example to provide something meaningful to arrayformula. Input=10 -> Output=2. Input=-10 -> Output = 0.

Comment: Please provide example that look like this: input = {1, 2, -3, 5, 10, 0, -1}, output = {1,2,5,10}. It looks like the function you want is `filter()`

Comment: Input={10, 5, 0, -5, -10} -> Output={2, 1, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: Please provide more clarification on what you want. Do you want the function to return one single value or an array? Your question is confusing because `max` and `min` both return single value, but you are asking about `arrayformula` ? Are you asking about optimization of your function, in which case you should really provide actual code?

Comment: I found similiar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887002/using-min-inside-arrayformula) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094059/finding-the-maximum-of-minimum-values-google-spreadsheet-excel/35625654#35625654). Will it help you?

Answer (score 1):

MAX is a aggregate function: those functions perform a calculation on a set of values and return a single value. You may want to check if this works (assuming your values in col A)

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A),--(A2:A/5>0)*(A2:A/5),))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question already states that `max` is an aggregate function. The real problem is more involved and requires more nesting with `min` etc. So your solution will work for the SSSCE I posted but will not solve the general problem.

Comment: Ok. There is no way to see the 'general problem' if you don't show it. As Daniel already mentioned some clarification of the end goal would certainly help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A>0,A2:A/5,0))
```

and

```
=arrayformula(filter(A2:A,A2:A>0)/5)
```

The first option will give you zero when there is a negative number. The second option will skip zeros, so you may end up with a shorter array.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, @daniel, but as I said I can solve this with an if function easily, but my real problem is more involved in which a simple if won't work. I think it won't help if I make the question more complicated. Note that for the solution with `filter` you actually do not need the `arrayformula` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

With the (new in 2022) MAP() function and an appropriate LAMBDA() function, it looks as if you can create an arbitrarily complex array output.

In your example case,

=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(dataValue, MAX(dataValue/5,0)))

should do the job.